# MVC structure of iOS app using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have experience on MEAN STACK (mongo, express, angular and node). I am using AFNetworking for rest API. I am not able to manage MVC structure of my app. Actually I don't have the exact idea of what should be in model, controller and view folder of an iOS app. Any project template using AFNetworking or other rest API or any link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) (a.k.a MVC) is one of the most-used design pattern of all in Cocoa world. Here, controller handles the burden of saving, loading model objects as well as interaction with external resources such as network calls and/or core data.

However, in reality, this design approach can result in massive controller objects that makes it messy and less flexible. So, to encourage clean separation of role, a better design approach is used to move out the logic of networking or storage into a separate object.

There are couple of such design patterns that are built by respecting the principles of MVC. It really depends on your design approach.

For example, One of such pattern is, [Model-View-Controller-Store](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/184396) (a.k.a MVCS), where you implement network/storage logic in "Store" Class (this is usually a singleton class). This also helps you to share common functionalities between different controllers.

I'd recommend you to read about design patterns in iOS. And, for your AFNetworking tut, you can refer [this great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial).